# CSS margins add up or are combined?

Tags: css, margin

Let's assume that we have the following code:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:100px;">test</div>
<div style="margin-top:100px;">test</div>
```

I noticed that sometimes it creates 100px of margin between elements and sometimes it's 200px (when we use certain settings that I'm not familiar with). I can't find any information about that in the specification. What does this depend on?

If we have `h1` and `p` in a blank document then the margin of `h1` will be combined with the margin of `p`. They will not add up. Whichever is larger will be used.

Comment: they look the same to me: http://jsfiddle.net/s7bWq/

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on this, but I think that's what browsers are supposed to do.  That is, use the bigger of the two margins.  Might be browser specific but I'm not sure...

Comment: DIVs will always create 200px of margin. But `h1` + `p` will combine them to 100px. This needs to be tested in a blank document.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is happening because your margins are allowed to collapse. Certain margins may overlap (mostly block elements) and form a combined margin defined by the larger of the two values defined in the computed element style rules - that's what is happening here. [This section](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-box/#collapsing-margins) from the [CSS Box Model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-box/) document explains it in detail.

**Edit:** As a point of interest, you can get around this (ie. break the collapsible margins) without breaking things (*much?*)in a couple of ways

- Making the elements `width: 100%; display: inline-block`
- Putting a `height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden` block in between the elements and putting a dot or something in it.

I forked ashley's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yjnk4/) to demonstrate. There are probably other methods but these are a quick a dirty way to get around collapsible margins if you need to.

Comment: Something that often gets lost in large sites is the line-height. If you set it at something that is less than the rendered height of the element you can lose some pixels of the margins that way too

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :) It's more complex than just a standard property that makes it happen so perhaps that's why it was hard to find this.